# Centrally setting Graphics.QualityXXX settings instead of from within PictureBox.Paint

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, graphics, paint

I have a PictureBox control whose Paint event I use to display some illustrations depending on app state. I need to set the following properties:

```
private void PictureBox_Paint (object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.CompositingMode    = CompositingMode.SourceOver;
    e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
    e.Graphics.InterpolationMode  = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    e.Graphics.SmoothingMode      = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
    e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint  = TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
}
```

This works fine but these properties are set every time the Pain event is fired which is pretty frequent. Is there a way to centrally set these properties? Please note that the size of the PictureBox control can change if the user re-sizes the window.

I know I can associate an image with the PictureBox control and keep a reference to the graphics object for that image instead. But I wanted to find out if the above is possible without an explicit image.

Comment: Setting those properties takes 0.00000001% of time needed to actually draw anything. Keep it as it is. If it is repeated in many `Pain` events (nice typo!), then make a method somewhere `void SetGraphics(Graphics graphics)` to set them at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a better solution, unless as @Sinatr pointed out, you need the same settings for multiple `Paint` events.  But that is just refactoring out to a common call.

You cannot get in front of the creation of that `Graphics` object, it's created by the graphics subsystem, so you're already doing the best you can...resetting the properties on-the-fly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe consider using Mapper Pattern. It is frequently used in Enterprise Applications, but I think it is useful in home projects.

The well known library is [Automapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) but you can simply implement your own mapper without redundant functions.